# How To Create Several Instances Of Spring Named Bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

lets start with code :

```
@Named
public class Dashlet implements GlobalDashlet {
    private DashletContent dashletContent;
    //OTHER STUFF
}
```

How can i create an other instance of Dashlet Class? 
say i have a method in this class like :

```
public GlobalDashlet getInstance(DashletContent content) {
        Dashlet dashlet =  new Dashlet();
        dashlet.setDashletContent(dashletContent);
    return dashlet;
}
```

as you know the above method wont work because managed beans should be instantiated by spring or else it is not a managed bean. so is it possible to reproduce a managed bean?

one more question, is it possible to attach e bean to spring bean container (so that spring can manage it) ? like merge functionality in hibernate?

Comment: Use prototype scope, if you are looking for several instance of a bean.

Comment: thank you . i need to create several instances on demand

Comment: Sure you can just autowire `Dashlet`, scope it prototype and every time for a new request a fresh bean will be created.

Comment: @dave-It'll create one instance for each request. That's the exact use of prototype scope.

Comment: @DarshanLila i guess it will create on each http request, what i need is to create it inside a code. just like using new() method

Comment: but i think i can use that :-?

Comment: You can also use it as a normal bean. But your created bean would me managed by you.

Comment: prototype-scope creates a new instance every time the bean is requested. request-scope creates a new instance for every HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your `Dashlet` bean to be prototype scoped.

Then, you can get new instances of the bean by making your consumer bean `ApplicationContextAware` and then use the `applicationContext.getBean(..)` to get bean instances when required.

Another way to achieve this would be using the `@Configuration` annotation as described [here](http://thysmichels.com/2014/05/01/create-spring-bean-on-demand-using-bean-lookup/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach to spring framework, you can use the prototype scope:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Example xml configuration:

```
<bean id="accountService" class="com.foo.DefaultAccountService" scope="prototype"/>
```

Example javaConf configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   public Foo foo() {
      return new Foo();
   }
}
```